# Python Regular Expression Finding a Specific Text Between Headers

Tags: python, regex

I'm just starting to learn about regular expressions in Python, and I've made a bit of progress on what I want to get done.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

x = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.SOMEWEBSITE.com")
contents = x.read()

paragraphs = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>', str(contents))
```

So with that regular expression I'm able to find everything between the paragraph headers, but what if I want to find paragraphs with specific words in them? For example, parse all paragraphs that have the word "cat" in them. I know that (.*?) find everything, but I'm just a bit lost on the intuition on finding a paragraph with a specific keyword.

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: If you want to do this right, as opposed to a mere hack, use [BeautifulSoup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)).

Comment: don't use regex to parse html

Comment: As a practice, how would I do it using regex?

Comment: @user2965071 Does this do what you need? `<p>(.*?cat.*?)</p>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use BeautifulSoup. Example:

```
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.SOMEWEBSITE.com").read()
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# now you can search the soup
```

**Documentation:**

[BeautifulSoup Doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

But... if regex has to be used:

```
>>> str = "<p>This is some cat in a paragraph.</p>"
>>> re.findall(r'<p>(.*cat.*)</p>', str)
['This is some cat in a paragraph.']
```

Comment: As OP insists he wants to use regex just for practice, this is not a valid answer to me. (I am not the downvoter).

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Added regex solution however this is reinventing the wheel. Practice? OK but definitely not as final solution. It's good that the OP will see other methods that are preferred for parsing HTML.